# Excel table reference gets replaced when table gets refreshed

Tags: excel

The following

=INDEX(Some_Table[Some_Name],1)

gets the cell from the array of rows from a table called "Some_Table" at the column of this table called "Some_Name"

And it works great no matter where the table "Some_Table" or the column "Some_Name" is.

However, if you delete/remove/refresh the table, Excel deletes the reference to the table and column and changes it to the worksheet:range, like this

=INDEX(Some_Sheet:some_range,1)

So we "lose" the reference to the table and to the column!

Is there a way to make "=INDEX(Some_Table[Some_Name],1)" fixed somehow so Excel does not mess with it?

Edit: Even if I use Data Validation to prevent changes to the cells Excel still manages to modify them and to remove the references to the table/column when it feels like it!

Comment: Yes, don't delete the table :]

Comment: Agree with the above.   Your problem shouldn't occur if you only refresh the table.   Also you don't use Data Validation to PREVENT changes to a cell, instead you need to have the protection set to locked (normally the default anyway, in the cell formatting) and protect the sheet.